# Can't republish an unpublished page on drupal site

Tags: drupal

I'm an administrator on a drupal site...

I accidentally unpublished the Home page, but cannot find any means to republish it.

From the content menu, I can select the piece of Content, but the only options are to make it sticky / unsticky , Delete or Unpublish...  even though it's already unpublished.

Help, please

Answer (score 0):

There many ways to set a node back to its published state if you know its nid, node id. Here are a couple:

- You can browse to http://www.example.com/node/[nid]/edit and tick the **Published** checkbox under the *Publishing options* fieldset.
- You can change it via a database query: `UPDATE node SET node.status = 1 WHERE nid = [nid];`

Comment: I found the nid and could see the edit screen, but there is no Publishing options fieldset.

Comment: Not sure how to run the query... any other ideas?

Comment: If you can run any arbitrary PHP in the Drupal environment (e.g. via [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) ) the following snippet will publish a node: `$node = node_load($nid); $node->status = 1; node_save($node);`

Comment: Or you can simply visit {yourdomain}/admin/content and check the particular node and in the "Update options" dropdown select "Publish selected content" and click on "update" button.

Comment: He stated in his question that it's not in the content menu option list for some reason.